# Object Oriented Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on an involved project using custom functions in Google Sheets. I tried to refactor some code recently to make everything object-oriented, and discovered that Google Sheets does not like objects.

Let's say I have the following in a .gs file

```
function Ob(x){
  this.x = x;
  this.toString = function() { return this.x;};
}

function print_Ob_wrapper(x){
  var ob = new Ob(x);
  return ob.toString();
}

function Ob_wrapper(x){
  var ob = new Ob(x);
  return ob;
} 

function print_Ob(ob){
  var result = ob.toString();
  Logger.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

If I put `=print_Ob_wrapper(5)` in a cell, the cell displays 5, as expected.

If I try to call `=Ob_wrapper(5)` in a spreadsheet, I get a blank cell, this makes sense to me, because sheets might not be able to display objects or something. 
What does not make sense to me is why `=print_Ob(Ob_wrapper(5))` doesn't display 5.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of testing, it seems that custom functions called directly from the spreadsheet cannot return objects. Your `Ob_wrapper(x)` function does that so the result is not properly passed `print_Ob()` function

You can work around that by having a third function call both of the other functions like so:

```
function test(x){
var result = print_Ob(Ob_wrapper(x));
Logger.log(result);
return result
}
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I'm mostly mad that I only caught this after a huge re-write of a bunch of stuff, and if it can't return objects, all of it is useless.